# Progress bar for a 'while' loop in R

Tags: r, performance, while-loop

I'm wondering if it is possible to monitor progress of a 'while' loop in R in order to get an estimated time to completion of a given algorithm.

In theory, since a 'while' loop executes until a given condition is fulfilled, it seems that use of a progress bar is rather pointless.

I suspect then that the best one can do is to use system.time() in order to measure CPU performance.

I am I correct here, or can a progress bar actually be employed?

Comment: This question can only be answered with reproducible example.

Comment: did you try googling this?

Comment: @rawr Yes, but all implementations demonstrate usage with for loops, since the maximum number of iterations is known beforehand

Comment: This really depends on the parameters of your loop. You can easily implement an infinite loop for which a progress bar would be meaningless, but there are definitely cases where there's a meaningful measure of progress you can track. You need to add more detail of what your condition is to make this an answerable question.

Answer (score 2):

Use progress_estimated in dplyr. Here is an example from http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/progress_estimated.html:

```
p <- progress_estimated(3)
for (i in 1:3) p$pause(0.1)$tick()$print()
> 
|==================                                    | 33% ~0 s remaining     
|====================================                  | 67% ~0 s remaining     
|======================================================|100% ~0 s remaining
```